# Is there any way to extract PGNs from a DGT live games presentation?

Tags: pgn

For example:

http://www.budva2013.org/live/d/tfd.htm

I have no particular interest in this tournament, but I often seen displays like this and wish to extract games without needing to type them out manually. Is there some way to download the PGNs?

Comment: how would you do that for this site,i tried the methods you described but i couldn't find the files. http://www.fairfieldcountychess.com/quads/tfd.htm
http://www.fairfieldcountychess.com/livegames.html thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://www.budva2013.org/live/d/tfd.htm

If you remove the last file name, you get the listing of the contents of the directory:

> http://www.budva2013.org/live/d/

The .txt files are files used by the Flash program to find the moves. But there also is a pgn file:

> http://www.budva2013.org/live/d/games.pgn

However, if I recall correctly, the pgn file does not always exist. If it does not exist, one way would be to write a script that parses the pos##.txt files which contain all moves even when the games are ongoing. I thought of doing that before the pgn files started appearing (probably an update of the dgt software?) in the directories, but never got started.

Comment: Does this work as a general solution? Consider, for example, http://www.boxhillchess.org.au/live/tfd_full.htm. Removing the final bit and entering http://www.boxhillchess.org.au/live/ does not seem to produce anything, and nor does http://www.boxhillchess.org.au/live/games.pgn. Is there some way to extract the games there?

Comment: @user1205901 That seems to be a bit nastier case. Apparently the file http://www.boxhillchess.org.au/live/tocks.txt lists the game ids (gaa99qt, g6ylh49, gdpam4l, g2jsq6w), and then you can download the game info at http://www.boxhillchess.org.au/live/posgaa99qt.txt (or replace gaa99qt.txt by other ids). With some programming skills, that file could be transformed to a pgn, as it already contains the moves in a pgn-like notation.

Comment: Ah, so do you think it's simply because the boxhillchess website uses an out-of-date version of the DGT software, whereas the budva2013 does not?

Comment: @user1205901 I have no idea, I've never used the software.